# Return unmatched string from regex using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have here a code that finds and replaces a string in URL format inside a certain element using Javascript. Once the there is a match inside that element it will rewrites the whole URL except the variable.

Basically, I am using youtube url and I wanted to get the videoID so if I write into my html element this url in this format :

```
youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rar2-VAfOI
```

the result must be

```
<b>videoID goes here</b>
```

The problem is that I cannot get the video url.

please see my sample code here.

HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="element">

youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IadsLclBOS8
<p>I am a text</p>

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwZqhx8eSN4

https://www.google.com/

</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("body .element").each(function () {

   var dataEXP = /youtube*.https:\/.[a-zA-Z]*.youtube.com\/watch\?v=/; 

   $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(

         new RegExp(dataEXP,'g'),

         '<b>return unmatch here</b>'

      )

   );

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/leojarina/56y6cebL/

Comment: why do you want video url, you already have that. What is your requirement?

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]; specifically, **put your code in the question itself**.

Comment: Hi Mohit, my purpose is that whenever I paste a link inside the element from youtube, I can directly get the videoID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplified solution to identify the youtube videoId. This regex would work for all kinds of youtube urls to extract video id.

```
function getYoutubeVideoId(url){

  var regEx =/^.*(?:youtu.be\/|v\/|e\/|u\/\w+\/|embed\/|v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;

  return url.match(regEx)[1]; 
}

getYoutubeVideoId("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwZqhx8eSN4"); // Returns RwZqhx8eSN4.
```

**Extract and replace youtube url's with videoId's from DOM.**

```
$("body .element").each(function () {

    var urlRegEx = /(?:http?s?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/gi;

    var $this = $(this);

    $this.html().match(urlRegEx).filter(function(url){
      $this.html($this.html().replace(url,getYoutubeVideoId(url)));
   });

});
```

Here is the implementation with html content as input : http://jsfiddle.net/valishah/m85n11ow/

Comment: Hi Vali, is it possible to return the match regex into an array?

Comment: Hi @leojarina. Yes it is possible . `$(this).html().match(urlRegEx)` will return an array of the matched content.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the `substring()` method in case you're only using YouTube links:

```
urlString = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rar2-VAfOI";

vidID = urlString.substring(33);
```

The result will be everything after and including the 33rd character, so:

```
"6rar2-VAfOI"
```

Comment: Thanks to that Idea, but considering that string is not in the variable but it in the element. What can you suggest?